# ASP.Net Core application - setting up memory limit

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, garbage-collection, blazor-server-side, application-pool

I am writing .NET Core application (Blazor), which is hosted in Webhosting under IIS. I cannot control IIS settings (it is under control of provider) and I have Application Pool limited to 500 MBs. Once my application reaches 500 MBs, the application pool is restarted ( and my app is restarted  as well ).

This is causing disconnection to all currently connected clients.

I am trying to set up the application to run Garbage collection in order to stay under 500 MBs, but I am not sure if it is best approach.

I have created file `runtimeconfig.json`:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.HeapHardLimit": 300000000
    }
  }
}
```

I am putting heap limit to 300Mbs to leave space for non-heap memory allocations.

And I have added to the project file `MyProject.csproj` following lines to make sure that Memory consumption is not increased by number of processors:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<!-- https://blog.markvincze.com/troubleshooting-high-memory-usage-with-asp-net-core-on-kubernetes/ -->
<!-- https://blog.discountasp.net/reducing-net-core-memory-usage/ -->
<ServerGarbageCollection>false</ServerGarbageCollection>
<ConcurrentGarbageCollection>false</ConcurrentGarbageCollection>
</PropertyGroup>
```

My application will serve very small number of users/clients and the response time is not very critical. Simply put: application can be "reasonably slow" , but it needs to run "without outages".

Edit: The high memory allocation is caused mainly by background job started by some users, which is consuming quite significant memory (it is recursive algorithm without memory leaks). Application itself after fresh start allocates 118MBs ( 14 MBs heap size )

Rewriting application to WASM is an option, but I will still need to host Data repositories (serving data) in the server under IIS and I would till be interested how to limit "memory".

Can you share your approach, how to "limit" memory consumption and instruct garbage collection to be more aggressive when 500MBs is going to be reached ?

Thanks

Comment: _"will serve very small number of users/clients"_ : then how do you get past the 500MB ?  First thing would be to see how much data is held in a 'session', andif you can reduce it.

Comment: But these constraints would make Blazor Webassembly a better fit. Is that an option?

Comment: Web assembly is an option. I will try to investigate how porting to Web assembly would fit into.

Comment: The high memory allocation is caused mainly by background job started by each user which is consuming quite significant memory (it is recursive algorithm without memory leaks). Application itself after fresh start allocates 118MBs ( 14 Mb heap size )

Comment: Then the solution will also have to be about that background job. Slim it down, host it elsewhere?

Comment: Background job is already slimmed. Moving to another hosting is not an option unfortunately. I believe that there must be MS recommended solution how to "limit" memory allocation.

Comment: If limit memory may be difficult, what about increase the memory of application pool? Set it larger so that it allow application run with higher memory.https://i.stack.imgur.com/vamtU.png

Comment: After investigation, it showed up, that Provider shuts down the application pool after 20 minutes without a traffic.  By the "traffic" provider means end user access to web pages. Provider totally ignores running background jobs, so the root cause of the disconnections is this "idle time".  I have recommended to move to another provider to our won server, where we have control over IIS, memory, OS etc...